# Kattis phone list, time limit exceeded

Tags: ruby, algorithm

Description of problem: [link](https://open.kattis.com/problems/phonelist)

My solution:

```
# get phone list and return true if list consistent or false if not
def consistent?(phone_list)
  index = 0
  last_phone = phone_list.last
  phone_list.each do |phone|
    index += 1
    unless last_phone == phone
      return true if phone.length == last_phone.length
      return false if phone_list.drop(index).find { |ph| ph.start_with? phone }
    end
  end
  true
end
# read file and parse settings
input = File.open('phone.in', &:read).split("\n")
# input = STDIN.read.split("\n")
settings = input.slice!(0, 2).map(&:to_i)

error_t = 'Testcase numbers need to be in range 1 to 40.'
error_n = 'Phone numbers need to be in range 1 to 10000.'
error_p = 'Phonenumber is longer than 10 digits or less then 1.'
error_u = 'Phonenumbers set is not uniq'

STDERR.puts(error_t) if settings[0] < 1 || settings[0] > 40

# iterate throw input and agregate results to output
settings[0].times do
  STDERR.puts(error_n) if settings[1] < 1 || settings[1] > 10_000
  phone_set = input.slice!(0, settings[1])
  STDERR.puts(error_u) unless phone_set.uniq.length == phone_set.length
  result = consistent?(phone_set.sort_by do |phone|
    STDERR.puts(error_p) if phone.length > 10 || phone.empty?
    phone.length
  end)
  puts result ? 'YES' : 'NO'
  settings[1] = input.slice!(0).to_i
end
```

I use [fast-ruby](https://github.com/JuanitoFatas/fast-ruby). I am stuck. I will be very appreciated if you help me improve my algorithm.

Comment: I am not lazy. I went for help after I spend 2 days for this task. And I think this site created for situation like this.

Comment: This site is for users who can write their questions by themselves, not for those who just link to a question and do not even bother to spell it out by themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bottle neck is not Ruby, it is the algorithm. The reason of TLE is because of the following code.

```
return false if phone_list.drop(index).find { |ph| ph.start_with? phone }
```

Assume the phone number length is O(L), phone number is N, then the time complexity of previous code is O(NL), and the overall complexity of the algorithm is O(N^2L), as N is 10000, it will fail the large test.

---

You should try some string data structures, for this problem, [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) is a good option.

First sort phone number with length decreasing, and insert the number one by one, if some number does **not** create new tree nodes, it means we find a prefix, and returns false, otherwise returns true. It reduce the complexity to O(NlogN + NL). According to the problem L is at most 10, it should fit the time limit in the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will try to change my algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You could identify the unreachable numbers as follows.

```
TO_DELETE = " ()-"

def unreachables(phone_list)
  phone_list.permutation(2).each_with_object([]) do |(f,s),arr|
    fd, sd = f.delete(TO_DELETE), s.delete(TO_DELETE)
    arr << f if fd[0,sd.size] == sd
  end
end

phone_list = ["213-749-6317", "(911) 749-6317", "12 37 63 21", "123", "911"]
unreachables phone_list
  #=> ["(911) 749-6317", "12 37 63 21"]
```

The steps are as follows.

```
enum1 = phone_list.permutation(2)
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["213-749-6317", "(911) 749-6317", "12 37 63 21", "123", "911"]
  #   :permutation(2)>
```

We can see the elements that will be generated by this enumerator by converting it to an array:

```
enum1.to_a
  #=> [["213-749-6317", "(911) 749-6317"], ["213-749-6317", "12 37 63 21"],
  #    ["213-749-6317", "123"],            ["213-749-6317", "911"],
  #    ["(911) 749-6317", "213-749-6317"], ["(911) 749-6317", "12 37 63 21"],
  #    ["(911) 749-6317", "123"],          ["(911) 749-6317", "911"],
  #    ["12 37 63 21", "213-749-6317"],    ["12 37 63 21", "(911) 749-6317"],
  #    ["12 37 63 21", "123"],             ["12 37 63 21", "911"],
  #    ["123", "213-749-6317"],            ["123", "(911) 749-6317"],
  #    ["123", "12 37 63 21"],             ["123", "911"],
  #    ["911", "213-749-6317"],            ["911", "(911) 749-6317"],
  #    ["911", "12 37 63 21"],             ["911", "123"]]
```

Continuing,

```
enum2 = enum1.each_with_object([])
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: ["213-749-6317", "(911) 749-6317", "12 37 63 21",
  #   "123", "911"]:permutation(2)>:each_with_object([])>
```

As you see from the return value above, `enum2` can be thought of as a "compound" enumerator.

```
enum2.to_a
  #=> [[["213-749-6317", "(911) 749-6317"], []],
  #    [["213-749-6317", "12 37 63 21"], []],
  #    [["213-749-6317", "123"], []],
  #    ...
  #    [["911", "123"], []]] 

enum2.each do |(f,s),arr|
  fd, sd = f.delete(TO_DELETE), s.delete(TO_DELETE)
  arr << f if fd[0,sd.size] == sd
end
  #=> ["(911) 749-6317", "12 37 63 21"]
```

In this last step the first element of `enum2` that is passed to the block and assigned to the block variables (by *parallel* or *multiple* assignment) is

```
(f,s),arr = enum2.next
  #=> [["213-749-6317", "(911) 749-6317"], []] 
f
  #=> "213-749-6317" 
s  
  #=> "(911) 749-6317" 
arr
  #=> []
```

The block calculation is therefore

```
fd = f.delete(TO_DELETE)
  #=> "2137496317" 
sd = s.delete(TO_DELETE)
  #=> "9117496317"
arr << f if fd[0,sd.size] == sd
  # arr << f if fd[0,10] == "9117496317"
  # arr << f if "2137496317" == "9117496317"
  # arr << f if false
  #=> nil
arr
  #=> []
```

so `"213-749-6317"` is not added to `arr`. The calculations are similar for other elements of `enum2` passed to the block.